# Cannot run perl script from PHP

Tags: php, perl, raspberry-pi

I have made a perl script which I would like to run from PHP.

When I do a normal example like

PHP:

```
exec("perl test.pl",$output);
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($output)); echo '</pre>';
```

PERL:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s
print "Hiii. This is perl executing in PHP";
```

And it prints out: Hiii. This is perl executing in PHP in PHP

But when I add my other Perl script (test2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

# Function definition
use test_sub qw( :all ) ;

use strict;
use warnings;

if ($ARGV[0] eq "te") 
{
  printf("te chosen to(%d)\n",$ARGV[1]);
  te($ARGV[1]);
}
```

And the new PHP looks like:

```
exec("perl test2.pl",$output);
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($output)); echo '</pre>';
```

I know that there should be a warning atleast eventhough i dont use any arguments, but nothing appears to be in the $output.

Even with arguments in PHP:

```
exec("perl test2.pl te 1",$output);
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($output)); echo '</pre>';
```

Nothing appears.
I have tried to see if the file in executable with the function

```
is_executable('test2.pl')
```

Which it is.

This runs on a Raspberry PI 2 with Arch and I do not know if this could have any impact?

The other perl file which is referred to is:

```
package test_sub; 

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(te);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (all => \@EXPORT_OK );

sub te {
  my @var = @_;
  printf("settingup te for %d",$var);
}
```

I have checked in the terminal for it self and here it works as intended. But I cannot get it to work through PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update 1**

I have found out that if I add the line:

```
use test_sub qw( :all ) ;
```

To the test.pl script which worked it stops giving an output asswell.

Comment: Why do you have the `-s` flag enabled in your Perl shebang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

First:

Below line

```
printf("settingup te for %d",$var);
```

should be changed to

```
printf("settingup te for %d",@var);
```

There was no $var variable initialized to print, its @var array you are using in your subroutine.

Second:

You should know how to write a simple php script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
exec("perl test.pl te 1",$output);
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($output)); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This works fine for me and output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => te chosen to(1)
    [1] => settingup te for 1
)
</pre>
```

perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

# Function definition
use test_sub qw( :all ) ;

use strict;
use warnings;

if ($ARGV[0] eq "te") 
{
  printf("te chosen to(%d)\n",$ARGV[1]);
  te($ARGV[1]);
}
```

perl module:

```
package test_sub; 

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(te);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (all => \@EXPORT_OK );

sub te {
  my @var = @_;
  printf("settingup te for %d",@var);
}
```

php code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
exec("perl test.pl te 1",$output);
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($output)); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

That should work fine for you as well.